# querySelector bug <a>

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I would like to understand if I have found a bug or I am missing something, looking at the code below selecting the tag `<a>` the `click event` brings me back its content as a target instead of tag `<a>`

```js
document.querySelector('a[data-photo]').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('Wrong target');
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<a href="#" data-photo><i>fake</i></a>
```

Comment: The click originates on the `i` and bubbles up to the `a`, you can use `.currentTarget` to get the `a`

Comment: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) for the above

Comment: So although the association of the event is on the `<a>` will it go to take the origin of the click?

Comment: read the docs for a full explanation